# How to set qualtrics choice labels (the text) in multiple selection box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I have a question requiring a multiple selection box answer input. I'd like to dynamically populate the items in this selection box using javascript. I see how to set the **value** of choices in javascript (setChoiceValue) but this does not change the actual **text label** the user sees! How can I actually change the label?

Comment: For what you are attempting, in almost all cases, it would be better to use embedded data and piping and/or choice display logic instead of JavaScript.  If you decide to continue down the JavaScript path, post the code you've tried to show you at least made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved my issue. I used embedded data from the individual's contact to then create options in the multiple selection box. Is there an easier/more automatic way to do this though?

```
var companiesAsString = "${e://Field/Companies}";    /*'Company A_Company B_Company C'*/
var companyArray = companiesAsString.split("_");

for (var i = 1; i < companyArray.length+1; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = companyArray[i-1];
    x.add(option, x[1]);

}
```